# FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete() throws a StorageException with url of type https://... but works with gs://

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I have an application where users can upload photos to FirebaseStorage and also delete them.
I use the following function (in a FirestoreService class) to delete a photo :

```
Future<void> deleteStorageData({@required String url}) async {
final reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url);
await reference.delete(); }
```

The url I supply looks like:

```
'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/masterdetail-t4lf.appspot.com/o/user_image%2F2022-06-15T22%3A08%3A04.308422.jpg?alt=media&token=f80ad36e-1a8b-45d2-86bb-ac1dc14b9991'
```

This throws

> E/StorageException( 5079): Object does not exist at location

and a 404 "NotFound" error, although the file can be accessed at that location and displayed in my browser!

If I supply the file's actual storage location, like:

```
'gs://masterdetail-t4lf.appspot.com/user_image/2022-06-15T22:08:04.308422.jpg'
```

the delete function works as expected and does not throw an error.

Here's what I get in my console:
[image: StorageException]

**Important observation:** The reference returned by .refFromURL(url) method stops at the first %3A (':') character.

Comment: Can you check again that the object indeed exists in the mentioned bucket?

Comment: @Prabir Yes it does!

Comment: The error message indicates that [the object is not there inside the bucket](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/handle-errors#handle_error_messages). I am not familiar with Flutter. I tried with NodeJS and it is working fine. Maybe, the code you are using, trying to delete the object twice(just a guess) and in the second time getting that error. Also I don’t think the name does not seem to have an issue as you mentioned in the updated question. If you think the name has an issue, can you try with some other object and see if that works?

Comment: @Prabir The object definitely exists inside the bucket, but the .refFromURL(url) method cannot handle the part of the String after /user_image/. I use DateTime.now().toIso8601String() as part of the filename to store photos. If I use DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch, the .refFromURL(url) method works without a problem.

Comment: Then probably it will be wise to create a [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/new/choose) or contact free [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support).